# Trying to write a Discord.py bot to interact with an API and send a message based on the API response

Tags: discord.py

It seems to get stuck at the `client.run('')` portion of the code and I can't seem to find why. This is my first time using both Python and Discord.py, so I may be missing something really obvious

My script:

```
import requests
import discord
import time
import asyncio

islandStatus = 1
i = 1

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

while i == 1:

    data = requests.get(
    "https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=API_KEY&uuid=PLAYER_UUID").json()

    if "mode" in data["session"] and data["session"]["mode"] != "dynamic":
        islandStatus = 0

    time.sleep(5)

    print(islandStatus)
    if islandStatus == 0:
        @client.event
        async def message():
            msg = 'USER Your Account Has Left the Island!'
            await ctx.send(msg)
    client.run('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```

Comment: `client.run` is a blocking operation.  It won't return until your bot stops running. What are you trying to do with that `while` loop?

Comment: I want it to be checking the (https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=API_KEY&uuid=PLAYER_UUID) api every 5 Seconds. How would I get it to run if `client.run` is blocking it.

Comment: Use the [`tasks` extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) to create a loop that executes every 5 seconds.

Comment: In this `@tasks.loop` function would I include them if statement encapsulating the `msg = 'USER Your Account Has Left the Island!'` piece of code.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on exactly what you want to do, but it looks like your actual process might not require a loop at all.  You may want to instead have an `on_message` event that checks the URL for the message author (maybe with some caching).

Comment: If you are new to discord.py, just create a command and put everything under it.